# selector with square brackets isn't returning object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML I have:

```
<div class="jqtree-element" node-id="5">`
```

and in JS I have:

```
for(var i=1;;i++){
  var object = $('div.jqtree-element[node-id="i"]');
  if(object.length === 0){
    var id = i;
    break;
  }
}
```

(I'm looking for free id)

I don't know, why it only returns `object = [prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is not `5`. Use string concatenation to pass correct attribute value to match. Also, if you do not expect `for` loop to continue incrementing `i`, include `else` statement to `break` loop.

```
var id;

for (var i = 1; true; i++) {
  var object = $('div.jqtree-element[node-id="' + i + '"]');
  if (object.length === 0) {
    id = i;
    break;
  } else {
    // break loop here
  }
}

console.log(id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few issues here.

1) Your *i* is not dynamic. Use string concatination and you'll be fine.

2) Your condition is wrong. You should check for the length with `1` which means that the element is found. You are checking for zero and it is true for `i=0` itself.

```js
for(var i=1;;i++){
object = $('div.jqtree-element[node-id="'+i+'"]');
if(object.length === 1){
var id = i;
break;
}
}
console.log(object)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="jqtree-element" node-id="5">
```